# Mutltiple check on symfony2 and fos User

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle

To migrate an old user sytem to a new cute symfony one, i'm trying to do a second check after fosuser password check.

It should be like this:

1. user enter its login infos
2. Fosuser check information
3. if check of fosuser is wrong, then do a first encrypt on user password and check the encripted with fosuser normal check
4. then, if password is ok, log user and if its ko, redirect to login form

It think i could do that by override the login action, or with an handler, bu I din't find the solution.

Could you please help me save days ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally after trying a lot of solutions, here is what i've done.
I have created a checklogin action, where I recreate the entire check and login logik.
I think the best way to do this should be a handler, but I could'nt find how to put an handler on the check password event (or check login or something).

I'm still interested in your solutions if you have a better way to do this.